# Jekyll baseurl and configuration for 'serve'

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages

I succeeded in setting up a Jekyll site, but there is one thing I would like to optimize. In my config file I have the value `http://mydomain.com/` as baseurl. Everything is working fine, except that every time I want to use the 'serve' command to have a local development server as a preview for a post that I am currently writing, I have to manually set the baseurl to '/' to make it work. Otherwise the server address would be `http://0.0.0.0:4000http://mydomain.com/` and non-working.

Is there an easy workaround for this, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

---

Just found out, that this command solves my problem.

```
jekyll serve --baseurl '/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "manually" ?

jekyll serve --baseurl '/'

Should work (and your terminal will remember the command). Now, if you are using [GitHub pages](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages#user--organization-pages), you don't really need the baseurl anyway.

Comment: Thanks, just found this solution on the Jekyll page too.

Answer (score 1):

Base url is the path after the hosts part in the url.
So your local parameters must be :

```
host:        http://mydomain.com/
baseurl:     ""
```